# cannot resolve method 'getFont(?)'

Tags: java, android

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html) states:

> Android O lets you bundle fonts as resources by adding the font file
>   in the **res/font/** folder.

As a result:

> You can retrieve fonts by using the **`getFont(int)`** method, where you
>   need to pass the resource identifier of the font that you want to
>   retrieve. This method returns a Typeface object. This encodes the
>   first of the weight or style variants of your font, if it is a font
>   family. You can then use the Typeface.create(typeface, style) method
>   to retrieve specific styles.
>
> Note: The TextView already does this for you.
>
> **Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);**
>   **textView.setTypeface(typeface);**

Unfortunately when I am using the above code I get the following error:

```
cannot resolve method 'getFont(?)'
```

Previously I used to do the following:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf");
```

But now when I try to create the **fonts** folder inside **assets** folder, it automatically jumps inside **res** folder.

I am using **android studio 2.3**. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: how are you calling `getFont`? do you have a valid `Resources` object?

Comment: Are you targeting to developer preview?

Comment: @njzk2 I don't know. Whenever I try to create the fonts folder inside assets folder it jumps out of it and goes inside res folder.

Comment: @Submersed I just created a new project and don't know much about the developer preview.

Comment: I was able to use the assets directory okay and use the getAssets() approach. I manually created it using the operating system (Linux in this case) and copied the fonts in. Allows me to support versions of Android that are a few years old but not necessarily ancient!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was not able to create **fonts** folder directly from Android Studio, I opened the project folder using **windows explorer** and created the **fonts**  inside `app\src\main\assets\` folder and pasted my font file there.

As so many other guys suggested in the answers I had to use [Android Studio 2.4 Canary](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) to be able to use Android O new features. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html) states:

> Only Android Studio 2.4 includes support for all the new developer
>   features available with Android O. So you need to get the canary
>   version of Android Studio 2.4 to begin using the Android O SDK. But
>   you can still keep your stable version of Android Studio installed.

Answer (score 36):

Use this method from support library 26.

```
ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.your_font);
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html

Comment: I have nothing called "context" when I started this project, it suggest creating `Context context` but I have nothing to pass to it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this might be late but here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/fonts-in-xml.html) for using downloaded fonts with API versions before 26 (compatibility mode).

Basically, you have to define the font description as shown below (using both attributes - app and android) then use the `ResourceCompat` class to access your font programmatically:

`Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <font android:fontStyle="normal" android:fontWeight="400" 
            android:font="@font/myfont-Regular"
            app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400"
            app:font="@font/myfont-Regular"/>
        <font android:fontStyle="italic" android:fontWeight="400"
            android:font="@font/myfont-Italic"
            app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400"
            app:font="@font/myfont-Italic" />
</font-family>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
Typeface yourFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/yourFont.ttf");
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I have updated the question. I used to do that but I am not able to create the fonts folder inside assets folder as it automatically creates the fonts folder inside res folder

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use it yet however as far as I know you can target Android O device only if you update your Android Studio to 2.4. And you need to update your SDK to latest build as well. Because as doc says getFont() available in Android O.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using compileSdkVersion 25 buildToolsVersion "25.0.2". Unfortunately no updates are available at the moment inside SDK manager.

Comment: Let your studio download updates from canary channels then you can download studio 2..4 preview 3. After that you can download SDK tool version 26.0.0

Comment: Thanks, I am currently downloading the new updates and will let everyone know the results.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a new method being released in O, you have to target the developer preview as your build target to use it.  For more info, check this [link](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html).

Answer (score 0):

They way I did it was like this:

```
private TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.
.

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface mTextView = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/your_font_style.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(mTextView);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This looks to be the closest one to be working for me, but it claims the path can't be found. The default folder name is "font", and I just tried adding "roboto_regular.ttf" as a test. Then it gives `java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found font/roboto_regular.ttf`

Comment: @Liggliluff you must add it under Assets folder like this `assets/font/roboto_regular.ttf` i think you added it to `res/font/roboto_regular.ttf`

Answer (score -1):

The fonts folder should be under assets folder, so try to create folder there.

Comment: The fonts folder automatically jumps out of assets folder and goes inside res folder