# Font resource could not be retrieved

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-support-library

I'm using `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` version 27 and in last release I used new font resource feature for my project but after a day I got 3 crashes for this line of code

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.my_font);
```

and the crash report says it's because of `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` and Font resource could not be retrieved. All 3 crashes happened for users with android version `5.1.1`. Is this a bug in support library or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: getFont was added in api version 26 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.html#getFont(android.content.Context,%20int)

Comment: but I tested and it's working on lower api's @lib4

Comment: Would you mind removing the underscore from the font file? Sometimes it is reported similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142235/cannot-resolve-method-getfont

Comment: that's just an example. my font name is something different and doesn't have underscore or other special character @lib4

Comment: @Amir_P Did you find a solution to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember what I did to avoid the issue :( @Fartab

Answer (score 10):

I got the same crash while using [Downloadable fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts) on API level 16 with Google Play services 9.2.56 (emulator).

If you're using this, then a **device must have Google Play services version 11 or higher** to use the Google Fonts provider (see this note in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#via-android-studio)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not using downloadable fonts

Comment: @Shrikant I just used a different emulator. On a real device you shouldn't encounter this error, because this version of Google Play services is very old.

Comment: @VadimKotov But I'm getting this issue on real device

Comment: @Shrikant I've got some crash reports from real devices too, I think [this discussion](https://github.com/AppIntro/AppIntro/pull/666) can be helpful. Will try to refactor my code according to the link.

Comment: How to test the version of Google Play services?

Answer (score 9):

Had this same issue, noticed a detail in the docs that helped:

> When you declare font families in XML layout through the support
>   library, use the app namespace to ensure your fonts load.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Regular"/>
  <font app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/myfont-Italic" />
</font-family>
```

I had been using the 'android' namespace before, changing to the 'app' namespace made my fonts load on older devices correctly.

Comment: Didn't work out for the downloadable fonts that I am using. :(

Comment: seems to do the job, thanks. tested ok. did not try downloadable fonts though.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a TTF file in R.font when using `ResourcesCompat.getFont()`.

It turns out that Android didn't like this TTF file for some reason. There was no info in logcat, but debugging showed that `TypefaceCompat.createFromResourcesFontFile()` failed.

I replaced the TTF file with another, similar font and had no problems since.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even after upgrading Gradle version to most recent one didn't work.
What worked for me was a really trivial solution, **updating the dependencies version to latest versions**. I don't know it might work or not in your case, but maybe you should try doing it once.

Answer (score 0):

while using **Downloadable fonts** on API level 16

The fonts need to be **downloaded** so its better to check the Internet connection and download them, even when they are provided from the fonts folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, so I followed another approach and it work fine for me.

1. Add a new directory in the **app/src/main** named as **assets** and make another subdirectory inside it as **fonts**
2. Add a font file (eg. poppins.ttf) inside the fonts subdirectory
3. If you are a Java developer then write this code in your Activity/Fragment file-

   ```java
   Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/poppins.ttf"); 
   yourTextView.setTypeface(font);
   ```

   and if you are a Kotlin developer then you can use this,

   ```kotlin
   val customTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, 
                                                 "fonts/poppins-Light.ttf")
   ```