# preloaded_fonts does not work programatically when not specified in any layout

Tags: android, android-fonts

After adding downloadable fonts using android studio (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/47793223), Im not able to load the added fonts programmatically.

```
ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.roboto)
```

results in the following error

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Font resource ID #0x7f080009
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont(ResourcesCompat.java:218)
at android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont(ResourcesCompat.java:196)
```

But once I specify the same font in some layout file like

```
android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
```

It works.

It also starts working programmatically now.

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825038/font-resource-could-not-be-retrieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the font programmatically, you need to create a font request.

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#programmatically) official documentation.

If you think that's lengthy process, you can always specify it in the xml and set its visibility to Gone if you don't need the view.