# Font resource ID #0x7f090000 could not be retrieved

Tags: android

Below is the code where I am getting a crash in crashlytics. But I am not able to reproduce this crash

```
 val typeFace = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, fontName!!)
```

can anyone help me out to reproduce it

> Crashlytics device  - Samsung galaxy S9 Moto z2(force) android OS 9
> and 10
>
> compileSdkVersion 28 targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825038/font-resource-could-not-be-retrieved

Comment: @ShaluTD this post is not helpfull

Comment: did you found any solution @ShaluTD?
I am facing the same issue