# Android: Crash: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException - Unable to find resource ID #<address>

Tags: android

I am getting Resources$NotFoundException mostly on Samsung devices. This is only happening for Drawable resources.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/screen_bg_color_secondary">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardInputSearch"
            style="@style/AppSearchInputContainer">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
                style="@style/AppSearchInputField"
                android:hint="@string/product_search_input_hint" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppSearchInputField" parent="AppFontRegular">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/input_hint_color</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:drawableStart">@drawable/ic_search</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">7dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">@dimen/screen_horizontal_space</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/screen_horizontal_space</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">@dimen/screen_horizontal_space</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/screen_horizontal_space</item>-->
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">text</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    </style>
```

**ic_search.xml** icon is available inside the drawable directory. The main problem here is above code run smoothly on almost devices but it throw error for a few users (~0.1%, with different device manufacturers and OS versions, no apparent pattern there)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xyz.app/com.xyz.abs.ui.product.SomeListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26 in com.xyz.app:layout/activity_list: Binary XML file line #26 in com.xyz.app:layout/activity_list: Error inflating class EditText
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f070278
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:281)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:949)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:724)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1072)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1017)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:991)
       at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1475)
       at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:99)
       at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:95)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:100)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:95)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:243)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:160)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1678)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1729)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1083)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1019)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:983)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1145)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1148)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:544)
       at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
       at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:1409)
       at com.praxinfo.quotationpro.databinding.ActivityProductListBinding.inflate(ActivityProductListBinding.java:100)
       at com.praxinfo.quotationpro.databinding.ActivityProductListBinding.inflate(ActivityProductListBinding.java:86)
       at com.praxinfo.quotationpro.ui.product.ProductListActivity.createBinding(ProductListActivity.kt:249)
       at com.praxinfo.quotationpro.ui.product.ProductListActivity.createBinding(ProductListActivity.kt:25)
       at com.praxinfo.quotationpro.ui.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:39)
       at com.praxinfo.quotationpro.ui.product.ProductListActivity.onCreate(ProductListActivity.kt:39)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Comment: watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825038/font-resource-could-not-be-retrieved

Comment: I have checked but not useful in mentioned case.

Comment: Just to make sure: Is the missinge resource in the commong 'drawable' folder or in something like 'drawalbe-xhdpi'?

Comment: ic_search.xml icon is available inside the drawable directory.

Comment: I have the same problem. Very few users affected for apparent no reason. Is your XML a vector drawable or does it refer to another image inside of it?